# ActiveRecord pulls records out in ASCII encoding in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, encoding

I'm trying to migrate my app to Ruby 1.9, however ActiveRecord keeps retrieving records out of my MySQL database with an ASCII encoding, causing "incompatibility between utf-8 and ASCII" like errors. I've tried setting the "encoding: utf-8" in the database.yml file, and I've also tried putting " #coding: utf-8 " at the top the errant file with no luck.  I thought it might be that the fields in my database were the issue, but even after converting everything over to utf-8, the incompatibility errors still exist.

Is there perhaps something else in MySQL that defines the encoding to ActiveRecord that I am missing here?

Comment: Can you give some example of the errors?

Comment: One example is "incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string)".  It's a simple regex with I have with gsub, looking something like this: sentence.gsub(/～/, "").  I know the error is caused because the "sentence" string is being returned as ASCII, but I don't know how to tell ActiveRecord to make it UTF-8.

Comment: Can you give the stack trace for the error?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently an issue with Ruby 1.9 and the mysql gem. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188740/activerecord-returns-data-in-ascii-8bit-under-ruby-1-9-2-rc1).

Should be solved by using the mysql2 gem.